# How do I display the text of an item in its listview?

Tags: c#, listview

Here's how I added the items and subitems to the listview:

```
public void PopulateListView()
{
    UI_LV_Words.Clear();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in _wordDic)
    {
        UI_LV_Words.Items.Add(pair.Key).SubItems.Add(pair.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

But no text is displayed in the listview. View is set to details. How do I make the text of each item appear in the listview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add columns to `ListView`.So it should be like this,

```
public void PopulateListView()
        {
            UI_LV_Words.Clear();
            UI_LV_Words.Columns.Add("Key");
            UI_LV_Words.Columns.Add("Value");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in _wordDic)
            {
                UI_LV_Words.Items.Add(pair.Key).SubItems.Add(pair.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**Result;**

[image]

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet,

```
UI_LV_Words.Columns.Add("Key");
UI_LV_Words.Columns.Add("Value");
```